# Vagrant Share Expiration time

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

During the teamwork development process that shares the same instance of Vagrant I always had trouble relaunching `Vagrant Share` due to it's session expiration. [Documentation](http://www.vagrantup.com/blog/feature-preview-vagrant-1-5-share.html) says that it's currently 1 hour (even though sometimes it worked only for 10-15 minutes). Is it possible to remove or extend session expiration time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently (*June 2016*) the expiration time has been extended even more to **8 hours** based on [VagrantCloud's documentation](https://vagrantcloud.com/help/vagrant/shares/what):

> Share sessions expire after a short time (currently 8 hours), but can
>   also be expired manually by ctrl-c from the sharing machine or via the
>   web interface.

However it doesn't seem to be any option to set the expiration interval yourself. And I don't believe it will ever be. The purpose of `vagrant share` is to share your work for a limited time just for your client to have a look or for your partners to do some testing and come back with feedback, **not** mid-term hosting.

Answer (score 0):

It is not currently possible to change the vagrant share session expiration timeout.